# XC8 conflicting declaration for registers (e.g. TRIS, SSP1CON1,...)

Tags: c, pic, microchip, xc8

I am new here. I am using the XC8 compiler and a PIC18F25K22 from Microchip.
When I am building the code, I get the error

```
xc8.exe --pass1 --errformat="Error at file %%f line %%l column %%c: (%%n) %%s" --warnformat="Warning at file %%f line %%l column %%c: (%%n) %%s" --msgformat="Message at file %%f line %%l column %%c: (%%n) %%s" -G --chip=18F25K22  -O"main.p1" "../main.c"
Microchip MPLAB XC8 C Compiler (Free Mode) V1.37
Build date: Mar 10 2016
Part Support Version: 1.37
Copyright (C) 2016 Microchip Technology Inc.
License type: Node Configuration

Warning at file  line  column : (1273) Omniscient Code Generation not available in Free mode
Error at file ../i2clcd.c line 11 column 8: (195) expression syntax
Error at file ../i2clcd.c line 11 column 8: (312) ";" expected
Error at file ../i2clcd.c line 11 column 12: (285) no identifier in declaration
Error at file ../i2clcd.c line 11 column 12: (314) ";" expected
Error at file ../i2clcd.c line 14 column 10: (195) expression syntax
Error at file ../i2clcd.c line 14 column 10: (312) ";" expected
Error at file ../i2clcd.c line 14 column 14: (285) no identifier in declaration
Error at file ../i2clcd.c line 14 column 14: (314) ";" expected
Warning at file ../i2clcd.c line 23 column 1: (361) function declared implicit int
Error at file ../i2clcd.c line 51 column 11: (195) expression syntax
Error at file ../i2clcd.c line 51 column 11: (312) ";" expected
Error at file ../i2clcd.c line 51 column 15: (285) no identifier in declaration
Error at file ../i2clcd.c line 51 column 15: (314) ";" expected
Error at file ../i2clcd.c line 84 column 1: (192) undefined identifier "lcddata"
Error at file ../i2c.c line 10 column 1: (1098) conflicting declarations for variable "I2C_INIT" (../i2c.c:9)
(908) exit status = 1
make: *** [main.p1] Error 1

Error code 2
```

if I comment this code line out, I am getting the error with the next register command (in my case: SSP1CON1) - I tried it with including xc.h
and htc.h but there is also the same error.

I found a similar problem in stackoverflow, but the problem was solved by putting these commands in a function, but mine are in a function.

Here is my code:

```
#include "i2c.h"
#include <xc.h>
#include <htc.h>
/*
 * subroutine:      I2C_INIT()
 * access from:     main.c/BOOT()
 * description:     Initialisises MSSP port for I2C Master-Mode
 */
void I2C_INIT(0)
{
    TRISCbits.TRISC3=1;                          //config SCL-Line as Input;
    TRISCbits.TRISC4=1;                          //config SDA-Line as Input;

    SSP1CON1 = 0b00101000;
    /*
     * bit 5:    Enables the serial port and configures the SDA and SCL pins as the
     *          source of the serial port pins
     *bit 0-3:  1000: I2C Master Mode, clock = FOSC/(4*(SSPASS+1))
    */

    SSP1CON2 = 0x00;

    SSP1ADD  = 39;                   //clock = FOSC/(4*(SSPASS+1)) - 100 kHz @ 16MHz FOSC
    SSP1STAT = 0b11000000;
    /*
     * bit 7:    Slew rate control disabled for standard speed mode (100 kHz and 1 MHz)
     * bit 6:    Data transmitted on rising edge of SCK
     */
}
```

Comment: Is this code for `i2c.c`? In this case I would say it is not corresponding to the one you are compiling.. And what is `I2C_INIT(0)`? Is it a macro?

Comment: This is not the full code of `i2c.c`. Sorry I am new to microcontrollers and C and I remember to read a code example of a guy who places (0) instead of (void), so I tried this. When I place (void) I get the error **conflicting declarations for variable "I2C_INIT" (../i2c.c:9)**

Comment: You should not put `0` for sure. I don't know who that guy is, but you probably misunderstood the intention. So it looks like `I2C_INIT` is define elsewhere. Is this the full error message, or there is more?

Comment: i edited the question informations

Comment: So... why are you looking at the *last* error? You should focus on the first one and fix it. Then go down to the next one. This is how we usually fix the  compiler errors.

Comment: haha thank you, but the last error remains.. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the register declarations (`SSP1CON1`, `TRISCbits`, etc., are declared in `xc.h` (and it's nested includes). Your problem may be that code in the `i2c.h` include is referencing definitions that appear in `xc.h`

Try reversing the order of your includes to place the system includes before your own (or third-party) includes.

In general, you should always place all system includes (i.e. those where the file is specified with `<>`) before your own (those with "").

Comment: thank you, but i found the error in another include file, and i removed the include file their...
but my new error is:
`make: *** No rule to make target ../../../../../../../Lukas_Fürst/AppData/Local/Temp/271d8c4c1fe4456cb5419e611bd1711e/PIC18F25K22/i2c.c, needed by i2c.p1.  Stop.`

Comment: I would suggest a clean and then a re-build of the entire project. That seems to fix that kind of error for me. But, it's very odd that your project contains a file in your temp folder. Try checking the `Projects` window in MPLABX to make sure that all the files there are in legitimate locations (if you hover over the file name, the full path will be shown).

Comment: thank you @EBlake I programmed first with Proteus and then Created a new project and copied the code in MPLAB X. I think the directory was too long.